# How to find a number between two characters in VBA

Tags: vba

For example, I have this string that reads `"IRS150Sup2500Vup"`. It could also be `"IRS250Sdown1250Vdown"`.

I am looking to extract the number between the two S. Hence for the first case, it will be 150 and second case, it is 250. The numbers are not always 3 digits. It could vary.

What I have tried:

```
Dim pos As Integer
Dim pos1 As Integer

pos = InStr("IRS150Sup2500Vup", "S")
pos1 = InStrRev("IRS250Sdown1250Vdown","S")
```

After this, I am stuck how to get the number out.

Need some guidance on how to do this.

Comment: There is a Regex COM component you can use in VBA to handle Regex. Please see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops. You can then use the Regex with groups to extract the data easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
Public Sub Test4()

    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim pos1 As Integer
    Dim strOrig As String
    Dim strString As String

    strOrig = "IRS150Sup2500Vup"

    pos = InStr(1, strOrig, "S") + 1
    pos1 = InStr(pos, strOrig, "S")
    strString = Mid(strOrig, pos, pos1 - pos)

    MsgBox strString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

As i suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916501/how-to-find-word-between-character-and-a-number-in-vba), the simplest way is to use Regex.

```
Sub Test()
Dim r As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim sPattern As String, myString As String
Dim mc As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, m As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match

myString = "IRS150Sup2500Vup"
sPattern = "\d+" 'searches for numbers 
Set r = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
r.Pattern = sPattern

Set mc = r.Execute(myString)
For Each m In mc ' Iterate Matches collection.
    MsgBox "number: '" & m.Value & "' founded at: " & m.FirstIndex & " length: " & m.Length
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this function:

```
pos = Mid("IRS150Sup2500Vup", 4, 6)
```

Comment: it will not always be 3 numbers, it could vary.

Comment: might want to add that to your question then mate, so we know