# How to find word between character and a number in VBA

Tags: vba

For example, I have this string that reads `"IRS150Sup2500Vup"`. It could also be `"IRS250Sdown1250Vdown"`.

In my previous [qn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913879/how-to-find-a-number-between-two-characters-in-vba), I asked how to find a number between 2 characters. Now, I need to find the word up or down after the second S now. Since it appears between the character S and the number, how do I do it?

My code looks like this:

```
Dim pos, pos1,pos2 strString As String
pos = InStr(1, objFile.Name, "S") + 1
pos1 = InStr(pos, objFile.Name, "S")
pos2 = InStr(pos1, objFile.Name, ?)
```

pos1 returns the index of the second S. I am not sure what to place in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx).

Note: you need a reference to MS VBScripts Regular Expression library.

```
Dim r As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim sPattern As String, myString As String
Dim mc As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, m As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match

myString = "IRS150Sup2500Vup"
sPattern = "\w?up+" 'searches for Sup, Vup, etc.
Set r = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
r.Pattern = sPattern

Set mc = r.Execute(myString)
For Each m In mc ' Iterate Matches collection.
    MsgBox "word: '" & m.Value & "' founded at: " & m.FirstIndex & " length: " & m.Length
Next
```

For further information, please see:
[How To Use Regular Expressions in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802/en) 
[Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)

Comment: is this available in excel 2003?

Comment: @lakesh, yes, it is. Try!